422 Python POST request involving file uploads and JSON data
i got a problem with POST request involving file uploads and JSON data.
Both sample code below will return

troubleshoot the 422 Unprocessable Entity error

Server.py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import UploadFile
class test(BaseModel):
   id:str
   question:str

@app.post('/request')
def request(item:test,input:UploadFile=Form(None)):
    ##do something
    return 


Client.py (Case 1)
import request
json= {"id":"1234acv","question":"how are you"}


files = {
            "input": (img, with open(file_path), mime_type)
        }
response =request.post(endpoint,files=files,json=json) 


it will raise the error

_content: b'{"detail":[{"type":"model_attributes_type","loc":["body","item"],"msg":"Input
should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields
from","input":"question"}]}'

i did try the following method as well
Client.py(Case 2)
import request
json= {"id":"1234acv","question":"how are you"}


files = {
            "input": (img, with open(file_path), mime_type)
        }
payload= {"item":json.dumps(json)}
response =request.post(endpoint,files=files,data=payload)


it raise error with

_content: b'{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","item"],"msg":"Field
required","input":null}]}' Server,py

What is the right format of to upload file and json at the same time?
